# Cannot resolve local sub domain on network

Tags: dns, hostname, troubleshooting

I have a raspberry with a dnsmasq server installed (via NetworkManager). I need to be able to resolve `*.raspberry.local` on my local (private) network.

**Here is my config :**

In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` I've added `dns=dnsmasq` to `[main]`

<strike>In `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local.conf` I've added `local=/raspberry.local/192.168.1.10` where `192.168.1.10` is my local (permanent) IP defined in my router's DHCP.</strike>

In `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, I have the following config ([taken from here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/configuration_serveur_dns_dhcp)) :

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
filterwin2k

localise-queries

local=/lan/

domain=raspberry.lan

address=/raspberry.lan/192.168.1.10

expand-hosts
no-negcache
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.conf.auto

listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

Also [there is no need to add a leading dot or wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37449551/11379030).

In `/etc/systemd/resolve.conf` I've added

```
DNS=127.0.0.1 80.10.246.1 81.253.149.9
Domains=raspberry.local
```

Which is supposed to tell my system to take localhost DNS first (with `*.raspberry.local`) and then Orange's (French ISP) DNS servers.

My problem is that, I can curl (and visit on :80) `raspberry.local` but not it's subdomains without adding them to `/etc/hosts`, and even when I add `any.raspberry.local` to `/etc/hosts` only my raspberry can curl it.

Also, in my `/etc/resolv.conf`, there is no sign of above config, I have to manually add my DNS server:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1 # my server
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search raspberry.local local
```

*(What is 127.0.0.53, ins't it supposed to be 127.0.0.1:53 ?)*

Am I doing something wrong here ? I'm sure my DHCP config is good in my router, and same for the above.

System :

- Ubuntu 22.04LTS
- Raspberry pi 4

Comment: The top level domain name .local is reserved for mDNS (Multicast DNS) which does not need a DNS server, since the host themselves respond to name queries. Try using a different domain name for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I can `nslookup raspberry.lan` but not it's subdomains for some reason (i'll edit the post with the new config). Also, I can't go on `raspberry.lan:80` with another computer from my network (I may miss something on my ISP's settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem using this dnsmasq config:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
filterwin2k
expand-hosts

localise-queries

domain=raspberry.lan

local=/raspberry.lan/

address=/raspberry.lan/192.168.1.10


expand-hosts
no-negcache
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.conf.auto

listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.10
```

and by changing resolved config using this :

```
DNS=192.168.1.10
FallbackDNS=192.168.1.1
Domains=raspberry.lan
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` won't change because `127.0.0.53` will handle everything.